# Regex for SSN in oracle column

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to mask the SSN details in my oracle query.

Used the below query for identifying the SSN formats and replace it with the given format.

1. ddddddddd
2. ddd-dd-dddd

> select regexp_replace('123-45-6789',
>   '(^|\D+?)(\d{3}-\d{2}-|\d{5})(\d{4})($|\D+?)', '\1*****\3\4') ouptut
>   from dual

If I run this query I'm getting the below output.

> *****6789

Similarly I want to parse the below format as well.

> dd-ddddddd

Or could have been better if anywhere the hyphen can be, but it should just read the 9 digits.

As I'm not much familiar with RegEx, can someone help me on building the regex for this requirement?

Comment: So, you want to mask the area number and group number only?

Comment: Yeah, I want to mask area number and group number. I just want to display last 4 digits only.

Comment: what if the hyphen is in between the last 4 digits?

Comment: For now, it is enough for me to add "dd-ddddddd" along with "ddd-dd-dddd" and "ddddddddd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture the first 5 numbers in a group, and totally ignores any dashes

```
-*(\d-*){5}((\d-*){4})
```

---

## Examples

- In: `select regexp_replace('123-45-6789', '-*(\d-*){5}((\d-*){4})', '*****\2')`

  - Out: `*****6789`
- In: `select regexp_replace('12-3456789', '-*(\d-*){5}((\d-*){4})', '*****\2')`

  - Out: `*****6789`
- In: `select regexp_replace('---12-3--4567-89', '-*(\d-*){5}((\d-*){4})', '*****\2')`

  - Out: `*****67-89`

Comment: Oracle does not support non-capturing groups (so your regular expression will raise an exception) and you need to select from a table.

Comment: Trying to use a non-capturing group won't raise an exception, but it won't work as intended.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for the hint, I've removed the non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse SSNs while ignoring dashes, the best way might be to replace any dashes (assuming these are the only non-numerics you need to worry about) before trying to apply a regular expression:

```
REPLACE(myssn, '-', '')
```

You can then apply a regex (although there may be a more efficient way of doing this; regular expressions in Oracle are pretty expensive):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( REPLACE(myssn, '-', ''), '^.*\(d{4})$', '*****\1' )
  FROM mytable;
```

Personally I might try something like the following, and avoid the regex entirely:

```
SELECT '*****' || SUBSTR( REPLACE(myssn, '-', ''), -4, 4 )
  FROM mytable;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP's regular expression ends with `($|\D+?)` so you cannot rely on the 4 digits of the SSN being at the end of the string.

Comment: Very Simple! Great idea! Thanks @David Faber

Comment: @MT0 I'm assuming those characters would all get replaced in the call to `REPLACE()`. If there are additional non-numerics then one can use `REGEXP_REPLACE(myssn, '\D+', '')` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take advantage of existing features provided by the Oracle Database, here is an opportunity.

Oracle Redaction feature allows for setting redaction policies in the database, such that when unprivileged users query the data, they only see what they should be able to, which could be nothing, random data, or partially redacted data.

One of the included features are some built in policies for Social Security Numbers.

If this feature is available to your current install, check it out as it could save you a ton of work in your application and reporting layers.

Here are the built in policies for SS#'s:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ASOAG/redaction_config.htm#ASOAG608

```
Example 5-7 Partially Redacted Character Values

BEGIN
 DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY(
   object_schema       => 'mavis', 
   object_name         => 'cust_info', 
   column_name         => 'ssn',
   policy_name         => 'redact_cust_ssns3', 
   function_type       => DBMS_REDACT.PARTIAL,
   function_parameters => DBMS_REDACT.REDACT_US_SSN_F5,
   expression          => '1=1',
   policy_description  => 'Partially redacts 1st 5 digits in SS numbers',
   column_description  => 'ssn contains Social Security numbers');
END;
/
Query and redacted result:

SELECT ssn FROM mavis.cust_info;

SSN
-------
XXX-XX-4320
XXX-XX-4323
XXX-XX-4325
XXX-XX-4329
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines of your regular expression / new requirement it appears you can have:

- Zero or more non-digit characters at the start of the string
- An SSN matching the formats:

  - `ddddddddd`
  - `ddd-dd-dddd` or
  - `dd-ddddddd`
- Zero or more non-digit characters at the end of the string

You can use the regular expressions:

- `^\D*\d{2}(\d{3})(\d{4})\D*$`
- `^\D*\d{2}(\d-\d\d-)(\d{4})\D*$`
- `^\D*\d{2}(-\d{3})(\d{4})\D*$`

To, respectively, match these 3 patterns and (since the only difference is the 1st capturing group) you can combine these into a single expression:

```
^\D*\d{2}(-?\d{3}|\d-\d\d-)(\d{4})\D*$
```

So your query would be:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'TEST12-3456789TEST',
         '*****\2'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```